# jQuery ajax request from asmx web service

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asmx

I'm attempting a request data from a HTTP POST asmx web service with jQuery's ajax. I've read numerous guides on how to do this correctly but with no success. From what I can determine, it is the request itself that is failing:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "http://data.niassembly.gov.uk/organisations.asmx/GetPartiesListCurrent_JSON",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify({}),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        if (data.hasOwnProperty('d')){
            msg = data.d;
            } else {
            msg = data;
            } 
            alert(msg);
    }
    ,
    error:function(){
        alert('error');
        }
});
```

The [JSON formatting is correct](http://data.niassembly.gov.uk/organisations.asmx/GetPartiesListCurrent_JSON) and when I save the content as a local .json file the function works. The service also has a GET option but from what I've read that won't work in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This:

```js
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  //url: "http://data.niassembly.gov.uk/organisations.asmx/GetPartiesListCurrent_JSON",
  url: "http://data.niassembly.gov.uk/organisations_json.ashx?m=GetPartiesListCurrent",
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  data: JSON.stringify({}),
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(data) {
    alert(data.OrganisationsList.Organisation[1].OrganisationName);

  },
  error: function() {
    alert('error');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That's worked, thank you! Odd that in everything that I'd read nothing mentioned JSONp (I don't have much experience, will have more to read!)