# Sending data from JS to ASP.NET-datatable using AJAX

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, webforms

I have the following JS code that checks if a user input is matching the data from the datatable pulled from a local DB using AJAX

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var button = document.querySelector("#next");
   var data = (<%=this.json%>); var count = data.sub.length;
   var ans = data.sub[answerPointer].answ;

   button.addEventListener('click', function() {
       imagePointer++;
       answerPointer++;
       updateImage();
       updateAnswer();
   });
   (function check () {
       'use strict';

       var snackbarContainer = document.querySelector('#demo-toast-example');
       var showToastButton = document.querySelector('#demo-show-toast');
       showToastButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
           'use strict';

           var x = document.getElementById("numb").value;
           if (x == ans) {
               var text = "תשובה נכונה, כל הכבוד!";
           }
           else {
               var text = "טעות, נסה שוב!";
           }
           var data = { message: text};
           snackbarContainer.MaterialSnackbar.showSnackbar(data);

       });
   }());
```

Some of the code is missing in order to reduce clutter.

My question is, how can I send data(like adding "true" or "false" into a specific column) to the server side of the aspx page.

Comment: Do u have jquery loaded? or you want to do it in core javascript?

Comment: @MuhammadQasim Thanks for the respond! I can work both ways, if Jquery is better i'll load it.

Comment: @JohnR try JQuery.AJAX() make sure u reference the Lib at top your scripts

Comment: @JohnR - You are using web forms or mvc?

Comment: @MuhammadQasim web forms

Answer (score 0):

**Note**

Verifying answers on client-side (in `js` code) is not save.

A malicious user can view the answers and send them to service or even call send AJAX queries to `back-end` stating that all answers is good.

So I would better send answer to server and did verification there.

Anyway, you cannot send ajax request to ASPX page. For this you need and ASMX service to accept requests. Having it you can send requires like stated in related question - [jQuery ajax request from asmx web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35244965/jquery-ajax-request-from-asmx-web-service).

Comment: Thank you! excuse me for my ignorance,  all I need is to add the file correctly in order to start working with ASMX?

Comment: @JohnR you need to create asmx service - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/308359/how-to-write-a-simple-web-service-by-using-visual-c-.net. And after it you can consume it. Please note this is legacy technology. So if you have modern site and can use `ASP.NET-WebApi` please use it . `ASP.NET-WebApi` much more straightforward. I suggested you ASMX as you use quite legacy technology `WebForms`.